# Any suggestion how to implement below Drag and drop file upload?

Tags: html, file-upload

[image]

I have to implement this drag and drop in my website. Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try http://www.dropzonejs.com, they even provide with examples on how to create the server side implementation.